# How to use git archive to fetch a single file from a specific branch?

Tags: git

Without cloning the repository, we need to fetch a raw file from a specific branch of the GIT repository. It is not clear from the docs of `git archive` how can we fetch a specific file from a specific branch.

How can we do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `git archive` and using the `--` to specify a file from the branch.

The command is:

```
git archive --remote=<repo> <branch> -- <path/to/file> | tar -xO
```

This outputs to STDOUT, you can redirect from there...